# How can Chrome extension functionality be run independently for each tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been developing chrome extension for dealing with different tab DOM but with  development so far, it seems that an extension can only handle one tab at a time.

**background.js** has method which calls recursively with 10 sec interval :

```
function sendMessageScheduler()
{
    console.log(tabId); // tab is created for each new tab

     timer = setTimeout(function(){

     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {text: 'click_question', 
                                      currentTabId: tabId}, doStuffWithDom);
            sendMessageScheduler();

     }, 10000); 
}
```

**pop.js :**

```
startButtonButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

      chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().sendMessageScheduler();

  }, false);
```

**contentscript.js :**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (msg.text === 'click_question') {
   }
});
```

**manifest.json :**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Click Question",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*.stackoverflow.com/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "question.png",
    "default_title": "Click Questions Plugin",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

What I've assumed before implementing above logic is that the extension will handle each tab independently but with development, it seems that if I execute `setTimeout` function for one tab, then other tab running `setTimeout` function stops and vice-versa.

How can I should handle this case so that different timeout function works independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all tabs with the following code

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var tabId = tabs[i].id;
        // do what you want
    }
});
```